# KDevelop 5.2.1 - Hello World Launch Configurations

Tags: kdevelop

I´m using KDevelop 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 16.04. I created a new C++ project, default with the Hello World example. For execution I need to start the launch configurations, but I don´t know, which launch configuration to choose. [image]

I tried the Compiled Binary, the result was "Failure: /home/.../HelloWorld/build/install has failed to start". Same for Script Application and install also leads to an error.

With KDevelop 4.7.3 there was a different option in the launch configurations (the name of the project), see the Screenshot. [image]

The option "helloworldkdev4" works fine, the program executes and shows "Hello, world!".

So which launch configuration in KDevelop 5.2.1 I need to choose to execute my Hello World example?

Comment: When you select `Compiled Binary` and then select `helloworld` target, it should be the same as selecting `helloworldkdev4` option.

Comment: Thank you for your help, now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Compiled binary" option requires you to select an executable target. Selecting "helloworldkdev4" in your case is just a shortcut for "Compiled binary" case and "helloworldkdev4" target.